# Why unbind Service onDestroy?

Tags: android, android-service

I've seen it mentioned in multiple sources, that if an Activity binds a Service, it should unbind it onDestroy. Why? Since the Activity is destroyed, it seems like the service will be unbound anyway. If it was "started" - it doesn't matter anyway. And if it was auto-started by the activity - it will close anyway if no others bound it.

So why unbind it?

Comment: Does the `Service` keep track who has bounded to him? I don't think so. If a service has been bounded n times, it should be unbounded roughly n times in order to be completely stopped. So, if you do not unbind when the activity is being destroyed, how the service would now he has no active bindings? It would run interminate. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: see [Additional Notes](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Additional_Notes)

Comment: @azizbekian I assumed it is unbound automatically by the destruction of the binder. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @pskink From your link: `and unbind during onDestroy()` - That is exactly what I'm asking - Why? Will it stay bound to a nonexistent Activity?

Comment: override `onUnbind` and check it out...

Comment: @azizbekian Please read the following: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html.  ~"**When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service**"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Activities need to handle configuration changes, such as when the screen is rotated, or the user changes locales, or the device enters night mode.

The default behavior of the foreground activity, when a configuration change occurs, is for it to be destroyed and recreated.

As a result, calling `bindService()` on an `Activity` is not a good idea. We want the binding to remain intact across the configuration change. Otherwise, our service will get destroyed and recreated, along with the activity (assuming that the activity has the one-and-only binding and nothing else started the service).

So, the recommended pattern is to call `bindService()` on the `Application` singleton. Then, you can pass your `ServiceConnection` from the old activity instance to the new activity instance. Retained fragments work great for this, as you can then call `unbindService()` in `onDestroy()` of the *fragment*, so that when the activity is "permanently" destroyed (e.g., user presses BACK, you call `finish()`), your binding can be released.

---

With all that as background, on to your specific concern.

First, you assume that a destroyed activity automatically unbinds from any services that it bound to via `bindService()` called on that `Activity`. It's possible that this happens, though I do not recall that being documented behavior, and it's the sort of thing that developers should not rely upon.

More importantly, in most cases, calling `bindService()` on the `Activity` is not the right approach. Otherwise, you get into the problems that I outlined above.

But, following the call-`bindService()`-on-the-`Application` pattern, I would not expect there *ever* to be some sort of automatic unbinding, because the `Application` singleton is never destroyed. So, if you fail to call `unbindService()` somewhere (e.g., in `onDestroy()` of the retained fragment), you will leak your service.

Comment: If the Application is not destroyed (which can happen if the system needs the memory etc. and please correct me if I'm wrong) then I don't _want_ the service destroyed because the user might want to start an Activity again. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: @ispiro: "which can happen if the system needs the memory etc. and please correct me if I'm wrong" -- Android will terminate the *process*, which eliminates all your Java objects. "then I don't want the service destroyed" -- then use `startService()` to control the lifetime, giving the user some means of stopping it. "Or did I miss something here?" -- [only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. It seems clearer to me now (if I understand you correctly) - If I need it running all the time (such as a Media Player) I will indeed "start" it and never need to unbind it (unless it's not playing anymore). And if I need a temporary service - I'll unbind it because it's useless. And the premise of my question - creating the service from the Activity - should be avoided anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @ispiro: "never need to unbind it" -- only if you never bound to it. There's nothing wrong with *both* starting and binding to a service, where "starting" is mostly for controlling the service's overall lifetime and "binding" is for a richer API between client and service. If you do bind to it, though, please unbind at the appropriate point. So, in the case of a music player that you want playing in the background, start the service when the user presses Play, stop the service when the user presses Stop, and maybe bind to the service if you have a foreground activity to show album art, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think you did answer my question itself, by saying that a destroyed Activity is _not_ necessarily automatically unbound. The rest is quite helpful, but that is the actual answer. Just noting this here for posterity :)

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the case you outlined regarding config changes is already addressed by Google here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Additional_Notes
~"**If you need to interact with the service only while your activity is visible, you should bind during onStart() and unbind during onStop().**"

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: That runs counter to the advice we were given by Dianne Hackborn, which is outlined in my answer.

Comment: This seems like a good approach, but I've come across many posts discouraging the singleton pattern. Thoughts?

Comment: @farthVader: Hopefully, those posts are 6+ years old. Singletons are unavoidable on Android. A running `Service` is a singleton. An active `ContentProvider` is a singleton. The `Application` singleton is a singleton. Many popular libraries provide wrappers around singletons as part of their work (image caches, event buses, etc.). Singletons should be minimized, you should be careful what you reference from a singleton, and try to use existing ones (e.g., tested libraries that solve your problem). In Java, singletons are a code smell; in Android, singletons are a code smell you get used to.