# Keep android service connection alive when rotating

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

My activity binds to a service in onResume and unbinds from in onPause so it can use the service as long as it is active.

Now I want to avoid this (un)binding if the activity is recreated only because of an orientation change (display rotation). Keeping the connection object alive (instead of creating a new one) is possible using onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance().
But I don't see a way to know when I can skip unbinding in onPause and later re-binding in onResume. What can I do to handle this special case?

Another thing I'm thinking about is, is there a way to get told when the app goes active or inactive? Then I could keep the service alive for all my activities and unbind from the service only if the app gets destroyed or put in the background. (compared to bind to the service for each activity, which I have to do to in order to unbind the service correctly when an activity is left and no other one is coming)

Comment: I found a thread suggesting to unbind with a short delay, maybe a bind is called right after unbind and in bind I could delete the execution of unbind and skip bind. I'm unsure if this will still work when the app really goes down and the delayed unbind must happen. What do you think about this?

Comment: I would look in the direction of headless Fragments that are retained between configuration changes.

Comment: I think you shoud read this answer here, and follow the suggested pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42100224/3210173

Comment: I tried this pattern. I still didn't fully understand where to unbind() the service if the app really goes to background or gets terminated. Fragment's onDestroy won't get called. Leaving the connection open is not recommended. Just to unterstand, is there a difference between this pattern and using a singleton variable for my data object?